# telegram bot with python: map_to_parent state is not recognized in nested conversation

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

My child convo does not transfer to the parent convo. Seems like the key in map_to_parent isnt being recognized? it just stops after the child convo ends. What am I doing wrong here?

Im also getting this warning:

`UserWarning: Handler returned state methodchoiceend which is unknown to the ConversationHandler.`

Here is an mwe: https://pastebin.com/pnve9gke

Comment: Hi. Can you show a full MWE? debugging conversationhandlers is always a bit tricky without MWE IMO, especially nested ones :D see [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/MWE).

Comment: @CallMeStag hi, Just added the link! man, even the mwe is tricky to make :D Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems in the example that you linked:

1. Both `method_convo_handler` and `count_convo` are both used as a nested conversation within another `ConversationHandler` *and* added directly via `dispatch.add_handler`. This is bound to interefer.
2. `return METHODCHOICEEND` is used in `done_method`, which in turn is used in
   `count_convo`. `count_convo` doesn't have `map_to_parent`.

BTW, if you give your `ConversationHandlers` a name via the corresponding argument, the waring that you mentioned will read

```
Handler returned state methodchoiceend which is unknown to the ConversationHandler <name>.
```

making it a bit easier to debug :)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: oh my god THANK YOU. You don't know how much time I spent on this! The tip about the name arg was very helpful, and helped me realize that the issue was the second problem you mentioned. (ofcourse I removed the add_handlers anyway) Thank you so much!